# Farseer / Unity - Kinematic Body and Sensors

Tags: box2d, unity-game-engine, farseer

i am working on a Plattformer-Game with Unity. I am currently using the Farseer-Port by [CatsInTheSky](http://www.catsinthesky.com/blog/article/2012/03/5/farseer-physics-box2d-and-unity-part-1):

I got some problems with...yeah, the physics. I don't really want to make things realistic in the game, but i want to use the CollisionDetection of Farseer.

So, i followed the Farseer-Unity-Tutorials and gave my Character a Box (BodyType: Dynamic). It behaves as it should:

- Falling down
- collides with the ground
- and it is kind of slippery

Then i started to make some research an Farseer and Box2D (there were some more helpful tutorials), because i only want to have my Character to move, when I say him to move, no sliding on the ground or something like that.

And i read some articles about good methods: Using Sensors for Collision Detection.

So i made four more GameObjects in Unity and called Them Back/Front/Foot/Head-Sensor, gave them a RevoluteJoint-Component and bound the PlayerObject with those four GameObjects (which also had a Body-Component and where marked as "Dynamic"-Bodies), i gave them all a Script which had a CodeLine like this:

```
        FootSensor.IsSensor = true;
```

So they wouldn't collide at all (since they were marked as Dynamic Bodies), but would register a Collision.

And now i am kinda stucked :/

I can't figure out HOW exactly to tell my Player-Body to stand still if he touches the ground.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work at all:

```
bool SensorOnCollision (Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, Contact contact)
{
    Debug.Log("HIT THE GROUND!");


    velocity.Y = 0;

    return true;
}
```

(The "velocity" Variable is a global Variable, where i put the Body.LinearVelocity-Information of my Player)

Then i changed my Player-Body to a Kinematic-Body knowing it wouldn't float or collide at all, until i want so. So Gravity doesn't affect it at all, too.

I just want to have my sensor tell me, if i am grounded, and if so, i should stay on this ground.

Would be really gratefull if somebody could help?

(If Anyone else is working with that Unity-Port, i would love to know how i can access the Farseer ContactListener.)

Comment: Firstly you need to give more detail than "doesn't work". You should look at the fixtureA and fixtureB that you are given by the collision function to check if one of them is the foot, and the other one is the ground.

Comment: Ah, alright, i'll post the Movement-Script!

Comment: `switch(e_MoveState)
  {
   
   case MOVESTATE.MS_RIGHT:
   {
    velocity.X = 50;
    KnightShape.LinearVelocity = velocity;
    e_MoveState = MOVESTATE.MS_STOP;
   }
   break;
   
   
   case MOVESTATE.MS_LEFT:
   {
    velocity.X = -50;
    KnightShape.LinearVelocity = velocity;
     e_MoveState = MOVESTATE.MS_STOP;

   } 
   break;
   
   case MOVESTATE.MS_UP:
   { 
    
    velocity.Y = 100;
    e_MoveState = MOVESTATE.MS_STOP;

    KnightShape.LinearVelocity = velocity;

   }
   break;
   
  case MOVESTATE.MS_STOP:
   velocity.X = 0;
   velocity.Y = 0;
   break;
  }`